# Trigger validation error message on Submit for Approval (Approval Process)

Tags: trigger, approval-process, approval-step

I have recently encountered an issue, which I do not seem to be able to resolve. I have set up an approval process that fires up if my `PickList__c` is evaluated true to the following value (or entry criterion): 'New'. When clicking on 'Submit for Approval' the PickList value changes to 'Approved', but prior to that I am running a trigger validation on two mandatory fields on the object (`Custom_Field1__c` and `Custom_Field2__c`). Currently, I have some logics on a before insert and before update trigger and I can use `add.Error` to return the error message on the fields. I would like the error(s) to be thrown on the same page, instead I am redirected to a second screen (titled Choose Approver) that looks like this:

[image]

I have a couple of questions:

- Why is it redirecting me to the Choose Approver page?
- Is it possible to return the error on the object? Is this possible to return it on the actual fields?
- Am I correct in including the validation on the before insert and before after trigger?

Ideally, I would like to be able to have the error displayed on the fields, but in second instance I can also consider customising the error on the second screen.

Any suggestion is more than welcome!

Thank you for your help,

Regards,

I.

Comment: So your approval process does a field update upon entry and that is what is causes the triggers to execute?

Comment: The trigger will execute on before insert and the logics within it checks if Custom_Field1__c and/or Custom_Field2__c are null AND if the workflow field updates to 'Submitted'. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add the error logic into the trigger before trying to insert

Something like

```
boolean b = false;

if(custom_field__c == null){ //test for the error
    custom_field__c.addError('your error message');
    b = true; //set the boolean to true so that update can't happen
}
if(b==false){ //only when there are no errors can you update
    update custom_object__c;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. Will this show the error message on the second screen? - this is what I would like to avoid

Comment: No, this will only show the error on the first screen. Let me know if it doesn't!