# How to display adderror() message on Approval Process accept/reject page

Tags: apex, trigger

EDIT:
My requirement is similar to this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66344/trigger-validation-error-message-on-submit-for-approval-approval-process)

How to display an error message on the standard process page using Trigger?

You can find the trigger on this [link](http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/making-rejection-comments-mandatory-in.html)

Here is the screen where I want to show the error message or anywhere in the screen:

[image]

Instead I'm getting the error message on a new screen as shown here:

[image]
Trigger code:

```
trigger RequireRejectionComment on Invoice_Statement__c (before update) 
{

  Map<Id, Invoice_Statement__c> rejectedStatements 
             = new Map<Id, Invoice_Statement__c>{};

  for(Invoice_Statement__c inv: trigger.new)
  {
    /* 
      Get the old object record, and check if the approval status 
      field has been updated to rejected. If so, put it in a map 
      so we only have to use 1 SOQL query to do all checks.
    */
    Invoice_Statement__c oldInv = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(inv.Id);

    if (oldInv.Approval_Status__c != 'Rejected' 
     && inv.Approval_Status__c == 'Rejected')
    { 
      rejectedStatements.put(inv.Id, inv);  
    }
  }

  if (!rejectedStatements.isEmpty())  
  {
    // UPDATE 2/1/2014: Get the most recent approval process instance for the object.
    // If there are some approvals to be reviewed for approval, then
    // get the most recent process instance for each object.
    List<Id> processInstanceIds = new List<Id>{};

    for (Invoice_Statement__c invs : [SELECT (SELECT ID
                                              FROM ProcessInstances
                                              ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                                              LIMIT 1)
                                      FROM Invoice_Statement__c
                                      WHERE ID IN :rejectedStatements.keySet()])
    {
        processInstanceIds.add(invs.ProcessInstances[0].Id);
    }

    // Now that we have the most recent process instances, we can check
    // the most recent process steps for comments.  
    for (ProcessInstance pi : [SELECT TargetObjectId,
                                   (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments 
                                    FROM Steps
                                    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                                    LIMIT 1 )
                               FROM ProcessInstance
                               WHERE Id IN :processInstanceIds
                               ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC])   
    {                   
      if ((pi.Steps[0].Comments == null || 
           pi.Steps[0].Comments.trim().length() == 0))
      {
        rejectedStatements.get(pi.TargetObjectId).addError(
          'Operation Cancelled: Please provide a rejection reason!');
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: You are doing a trigger on Invoice_Statement__c yet showing an Approval process for opportunity? Not sure how you even got the error to occur. Regardless, the Approval process is a VF page IIRC and if the errors are not caught by that page then they display like you have found. Nothing you can do about it. In the link you put in your question, the approval was done via chatter which does handle errors appropriately which is why the messages displays as you would like

Comment: @Eric: I forgot to mentioned that the screen shot of the approval process is just an sample page to show and it has nothing to do with trigger.  What is IIRC ?

Comment: If I remember/recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is by Design from Salesforce. We do not have any control over this.

Suggest you to put this idea in [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch)

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: quite sure, otherwise wait for someone to chime in